# Converting a text to a number using GNU MP library

Tags: c

I am trying to make an encryption program. First i am trying to convert a text input to a number and i am using the function mpz_import(...) to convert. For example i am trying a small program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
  mpz_t number;
  const char *string;
  gmp_printf("Type something you would like to convert to number:\n");
  gmp_scanf("%s", string);
  mpz_init(number);
  mpz_import(number, strlen(string), 1, 1, 0, 0, string);
  gmp_printf("The number of the text you type is: %Zd", number);
  mpz_clear(number);
}
```

After the program asking for an input always take the message zsh: segmantation fault ./test. Can you help me with the problem?

Comment: *string* is a non initialized pointer, give an existing array and also limit the read size, for instance `char string[16]; .. gmp_scanf("%15s", string);` else your program will not be secure at all, not good for a master about security ...

Comment: there is no memory to read string into